# Databricks Low Shuffle Merge design

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

Does anyone know how Low shuffle merge has been implemented in Databricks runtime?

I tried searching for any white paper on it but the only available information is very high level and couldn't find any details on how it works under the hood.

Comment: Why do you need this information?